# Unable to use Drawer method openDrawer() in component React Native Android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am implementing Drawer in android using react native and trying to create different file for drawer menu code and drawer content code. To do this I have created react component in different. I am able to do all work in these file but I need drawer reference to perform some operations of drawer in component files. Here is my code, How can I pass reference of drawer to other component file to use drawer methods like openDrawer().

```
      'use strict';

    var React = require('react-native');
    var { View,
          StyleSheet,
          TouchableHighlight,
          } = React;

    var DrawerLayout = require('react-native-drawer-layout');
    var DrawerScreen = require('./DrawerScreen');
    var DrawerMenu = require('./DrawerMenu');

    var DrawerLayoutExample = React.createClass({

      render: function() {
        var navigationView = (
          <View >
               <DrawerMenu/>
          </View>
        );

        return (
          <DrawerLayout
            onDrawerSlide={(e) => this.setState({drawerSlideOutput: JSON.stringify(e.nativeEvent)})}
            onDrawerStateChanged={(e) => this.setState({drawerStateChangedOutput: JSON.stringify(e)})}
            drawerWidth={200}
            ref={(drawer) => { return this.drawer = drawer  }}
            keyboardDismissMode="on-drag"
            renderNavigationView={() => navigationView}>
            <View style={styles.container}>
 // Here is content component for drawer, need to refer drawer reference
            <DrawerScreen ></DrawerScreen>
            </View>
          </DrawerLayout>
        );
      }
    });

    var styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'column',
      },
     });

    module.exports = DrawerLayoutExample;
```

DrawerScreen.js

```
'use strict';
var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Dimensions,
  Image,
  TouchableHighlight,
  TextInput,
} = React;

var deviceWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;

var DrawerScreen = React.createClass({


  render: function() {
    return (

        <View style={styles.container}>

          <Text style={styles.welcome}>Content!</Text>

          <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.state.openDrawer()}>
            <Text>Open drawer</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
          <TextInput style={styles.inputField} />
        </View>
    );
  },

});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container: {
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      flex: 1,
          flexDirection: 'column',
    },
    inputField: {
      backgroundColor: '#F2F2F2',
      height: 40,
    },
});

module.exports = DrawerScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess the problem is, that you used 
`this.state.openDrawer()`
to call the drawer.

Try using 
`this.drawer.openDrawer()`

hope this helps